# Android Exception Intent, activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am currently using android studio and I have put in my activities in the manifest file and I believe I am calling it correctly. I keep getting this error though:

Caused by: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.ca.android.easycall.customers1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

This is my Call:

```
Intent actCustomers1 = new Intent(this, customers1.class);
startActivity(actCustomers1);
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ca.android.easycall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ca.android.easycall.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".customers1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customers1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".customers2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customers2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why is this required:     <permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> when you have uses-permission?

Comment: hii,, Please check the path you have define in android:name is correct. for your every activity.

Answer (score 3):

From what you posted, it looks like your class `customers1` is not declared in package `com.ca.android.easycall`

When you have something like `android:name=".customers1"`, Android compiler will try to prepend it with package name `package="com.ca.android.easycall"`, so it becomes `com.ca.android.easycall.customers1`

Quoted from Android official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> android:name
>
> The name of the class that implements the activity, a
>   subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified
>   class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity").
>   However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a
>   period (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to
>   the package name specified in the  element.

However because you got the error log:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.ca.android.easycall.customers1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So it must be either customers1 is not declared or customers1 is not in `com.ca.android.easycall` package

Comment: The confusing part is it is declared in my manifest and it is in the package. http://i.imgur.com/EKSpJcZ.png

Comment: Have you put `package com.ca.android.easycall;` at the top of your files in that package? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html

Comment: I agree with Graham, you should check if you have some other package in that package declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
<activity
        android:name="com.ca.android.easycall.customers1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customers1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ca.android.easycall.customers2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customers2" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your `Manifest.xml` like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.ca.android.easycall.customers1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customers1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ca.android.easycall.customers2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customers2" >
    </activity>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This does not make a difference. When you have dot at front, Android will auto append package name at front of the activity name

Answer (score 0):

Check the package at the top of the activity file. Maybe the activities have a different package than your application.

If it is different change it to the one you have in your manifest **com.ca.android.easycall**